# Join lists and tuple in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I want to convert

```
[(3L, (2L,)), (108L, (11L,))]
```

to

```
(3L, (2L,), 108L, (11L,))
```

I've tried to use this code to do this

```
 ["".join(map(str, val)) for val in list]
```

and my output becomes

```
('3(2L,)', '108(11L,)')
```

How would I go about correctly converting this..?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [11]: lst = [(3L, (2L,)), (108L, (11L,))]

In [12]: tuple(el for subl in lst for el in subl)
Out[12]: (3L, (2L,), 108L, (11L,))
```

Comment: `l` can be confused with `1`. It is recommended not to use that name

Comment: @jamylak: Fair enough. Changed.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [chain](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) from itertools:

```
In [1]: from itertools import chain
In [2]: a = [(3L, (2L,)), (108L, (11L,))]
In [3]: tuple(chain(*a))
Out[3]: (3L, (2L,), 108L, (11L,))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

L = [(3L, (2L,)), (108L, (11L,))]
tuple(chain.from_iterable(L))
```